# Webpack: @import in css or scss from bower

Tags: webpack, css-loader

Using Webpack, from my css (or scss) file, I'm trying to reach in to a bower package to import a css file.  With NPM modules, this seems to work easily:

`app.scss`

```
@import "~normalize.css/normalize.css";
body {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

In the case of Bower, I've been trying to use `resolve.alias` to get this to work without any success:

`webpack.config.js`

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'css-spinners' : '/bower_components/css-spinners/css/spinner'
    }
  }
```

`app.scss`

```
@import "css-spinners/three-quarters.css";
body {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

This is the error message:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/autoprefixer-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/app.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./css-spinners/three-quarters.css in /Users/{project root folder}/src/styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/autoprefixer-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/app.scss 4:10-97
```

I don't want to load this component through `main` in `bower.json` because I only want to import one specific file from the component.

Any way to @import a css file from a bower component?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this (sorry, not the greatest way to start an answer!) but i have been able to resolve from various directories in the past using the `resolve.modules` array.

Rather than using alias, Have you tries something like the following?

**webpack.config.js**

```
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.scss']
  },
```

**app.scss**

```
@import "~css-spinners/css/spinner/three-quarters.css";
body {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```